# how to make custom layout for alertdialog wrap content

Tags: android

I have created a custom layout with 3 buttons for alertdialog which is working fine. I am trying to make the layout so that width and height layout will be only wrap its content i.e. no extra width/height but I am unable to do so. Can you help me on this please?

Here is my custom layout for alertdialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#00ffffff"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_menu"
        >

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/wowButtonId"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/love_icon"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_for_round_menu_like_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

  <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/blehButtonId"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bleh"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_for_round_menu_like_button"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dislikeButtonId"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dislike_icon"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_for_round_menu_like_button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

alertDialog implement in adapter code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
View view1=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_for_long_like_button_option,null);

                ImageButton wow=(ImageButton) view1.findViewById(R.id.wowButtonId);
                ImageButton disLike=(ImageButton) view1.findViewById(R.id.dislikeButtonId);
                ImageButton bleh=(ImageButton) view1.findViewById(R.id.blehButtonId);

                wow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"wow",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                disLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"dislike",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                bleh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"bleh",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.setView(view1);

                alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: What do you use, DialogFragment?

Comment: no just alertdialog for on button click option in recylerview adapter

Comment: show me your alertdialog code

Comment: @Arti i have added the code please check...

Comment: @AAA please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

try this on your class file where you inflate your alert dialog...

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            Window window = alertDialog.getWindow();
            lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
//This makes the dialog take up the full width
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            window.setAttributes(lp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Summary: Use **RelativeLayout** tag at the root in your custom layout

I had two alert dialogs in the application I was writing. One of them did not wrap content, while the other did. The one with the LinearLayout tag at its root, was expanding a tad more in height, than the space its contents really occupied.
I tried setting the width and height properties to *wrap_content* on the LinearLayout but to no avail.

The one with the RelativeLayout tightly wrapped its contents. The code structure to achieve this would look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <!-- More widgets -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Although care must be taken, that the inner LinearLayout should still specify *wrap_content*. You can of course specify *match_parent* if your intention is to present an elongated dialog, the intentions for doing so, which I would leave it to the developer.

Android Studio still warns me that *The LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless*. I do not consider this a solution to the problem, rather it's just a fix. And, I should mention that I've always had these layout problems working with Android. This, I feel, is a more saner approach as it keeps the code modifications down to the layout.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for set layout and show dialog

```
  public void showDialog() {

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_long_like_button_option, null);

    final TextView txtOk = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.txtOk);
    final TextView txtCancel = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.txtCancel);


    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));


    txtOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            alertDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });


    txtCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: this is working ,this making background transparent but i wanted to make like the way facebook like button long press show a popup menu.can you help me to do that please? BTW thanks and i have marked your ans correct

Comment: I have check how to customize dialog but I have some reference for facebook emoji library Please check this [https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3839)

Comment: one more problem, why alertdialog showing in fixed position instead clicked buttons position ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the width of the inflated view directly when the dialog is shown and therefore has a window

```
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setView(myView)
    .create()


dialog.setOnShowListener {
    dialog.window?.setLayout(
        myView.width,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
}
```